# Generate wind turbine symbol in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, symbology

I need to make a windmill symbol in GeoServer (similar to the symbol in QGIS symbols). I tried taking the SLD to GeoServer but it doesn't work. So I tried with simple lines and points in GeoServer but it doesn't work. It shows following error message:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Graphic: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @6aef4eb8)`

The style I tried in GeoServer is:

```
       <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>line</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#d13a78</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>11</se:Size>
          <se:Rotation>
            <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
          </se:Rotation>
          <se:Displacement>
            <se:DisplacementX>17</se:DisplacementX>
            <se:DisplacementY>0</se:DisplacementY>
          </se:Displacement>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>line</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#d13a78</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>14</se:Size>
          <se:Displacement>
            <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
            <se:DisplacementY>3</se:DisplacementY>
          </se:Displacement>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>line</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#987db7</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#d13a78</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>7</se:Size>
          <se:Rotation/>
          <se:Displacement>
            <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
            <se:DisplacementY>-6</se:DisplacementY>
          </se:Displacement>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>line</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#d13a78</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>7</se:Size>
          <se:Rotation>
            <ogc:Literal>130</ogc:Literal>
          </se:Rotation>
          <se:Displacement>
            <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
            <se:DisplacementY>-6</se:DisplacementY>
          </se:Displacement>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>line</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#d13a78</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>7</se:Size>
          <se:Rotation>
            <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
          </se:Rotation>
          <se:Displacement>
            <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
            <se:DisplacementY>-3</se:DisplacementY>
          </se:Displacement>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d13a78</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#d13a78</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>2</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

What mistake am I making? Is there any other way to get a symbol like [image: symbol for wind turbine-from QGIS library]
[image: symbol-windturbine_simple]

Comment: Using SVG or png symbols feels much simpler, or at least less writing https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html. Notice that for reading symbols from URL the servers must be whilelisted in recent GeoServer versions. The demo data directory that is installed with GeoServer has a style "burg.sld" that is using a SVG symbol.